# iGUI dll could not be found

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

Previously, I was able to build an iOS project with Unity 4.6.2, but I can't with Unity 5.1.1. I get an `iGUI` dll could not be found error:

```
ArgumentException: The Assembly UnityEditor is referenced by iGUI ('Assets/lib/igui/Runtime/iGUI.dll'). But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 cache, BuildTarget target) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:154)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 cache, BuildTarget target) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:160)
UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[] paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, BuildTarget target) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:192)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Could you do the following?
- Close the project
- backup the project
- delete its Library folder
- reopen the project, wait for Unity to reimport.
What happens after you did thet?